# 2 ports for frontend and backend. How many load balancers required and how to configure them in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

In gcp I have created 2 template groups one for backend which internally contains 2 instances and other for frontend with 2 instances. Frontend(https) works on port 8081 and backend on port 8444. So how should I configure load balancer for both

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a combination of load balancers, one for external HTTPS traffic and another internal load balancer for your backend traffic. This is a common pattern in multi-tier web design. See ["External Versus Internal Load Balancing"](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#external_versus_internal_load_balancing) for more details and examples.

Comment: How these two load balancers can talk to each other. Where to put that link.

Answer (score 0):

Create a forwarding rule [1] to direct network traffic to another load balancer

[1]https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/create